# Java приложение (десктоп и апплет) на разных ОС и броузерах

Tags: java, ios, веб-программирование

Добрый день! Разрабатываем Java апплет, способный работать в десктоп режиме на Windows, Linux, iOs. На клиенте предполагается осуществить только логику приложения и пользовательский интерфейс. Подзадачи решаются отдельными модулями, с которым клиент взаимодействует через абстрактный слой: апплет работает с веб-службой, где реализованы эти модули, для десктоп - хранятся в виде подключаемых библиотек. В первом случаи слоем можно назвать механизм взаимодействия клиент-сервер, во втором - интерфейсные функции подключения локальных библиотек, функции запроса, доступ к локальным хранилищам данных и т.д.

1. Запустили SOAP-службу на Java, проблем взаимодействия с клиентом пока не видим, для нас важна безопасность канала, можно ли по REST передавать данные не беспокоясь за их сокрытость от чужих?
2. Апплет нормально работает на iExplore, firefox и chrome, но в Opera ведет себя не адекватно, инициализация начальных данных происходит (выскакивает наш messageBox до загрузки формы), но форма не отображается, видно только синий фон, с чем бы это могло быть связано? Как можно апплеты отлаживать?
3. Десктоп-версия на Windows (XP, 7) и Ubuntu 10.04 выглядит по разному, похоже все отличие только в шрифтах, с чем бы это могло быть связано, какие пути решения? Какие еще неожиданности можно ожидать?
4. Беспокоит вопрос о запуске апплета в iPad, iPod, какая у них JVM устанавливается? Особенности разработки под iOS?

Работаем на NetBeans 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Оба способа позволяют использовать шифрование за счёт HTTPS.
2. Так с ходу трудно сказать.. но апплеты отлаживаются примерно так же, как и обычные приложения + хорошее логгирование никто не отменял
3. Они и должны выглядеть по разному: всякие размеры и оформление зависит от системных настроек. По идее, многое вы можете настроить намертво, например, Look And Feel можно указать чётко и всякие кнопки будут выглядеть одинаково. Если AWT используете, то кнопки будут по разному выглядеть.
4. Напрасно беспокоитесь. Ответ простой - никакая JVM там не устанавливается. Ваш апплет там работать не будет. Вам следует подумать о GWT. Java с его помощью транслирутся в JavaScript, так что приложение будет работать просто в браузере, в том числе и на ios.

**UPD**

1. GWT развивается и поддерживается вполне активно. На инкубаторе полно компонентов для него.
2. Ограничения такие же, как и у любого JavaScript-приложения, такие как отсутствие доступа к диску, например. Документы, что вам нужны, придётся генерировать на сервере и на клиентской стороне предлагать пользователю его скачать.

Comment: Можно ли интерфейс писать на GWT, а некоторые подключаемые модули оставить на java? Или это уже излишнее усложнение? Будет ли это работать без JVM?

Comment: Нельзя смешивать внешние java-библиотеки и GWT. По крайней мере, обычно. И да, GWT работает без JVM. В этом заклюается идея. Также это снимает вопрос SOAP vs RESTful, так как там используется GWT-RPC, сделанный очень удобно.

Comment: Спасибо за идею! JVM я имел ввиду, если подключаем внешние библиотеки, значит это не самый хороший подход. Я правильно понял, если выбираем GWT, то все приложение пишется на нем, веб-сервера тоже?

Comment: Веб-сервер работает как обычно. Но для работы GWT-RPC придётся к серверу подключить GWT-библиотеки. Соответственно, на сервере вы вольны использовать всё, что пожелаете.

Comment: Еще несколько вопросов:  
1. Проект предполагается поддерживать в течении нескольких лет, каковы песпективы GWT относительно поддержки и развития?
2. Есть ли у GWT ограничения? Приложение должно будет генерировать текстовые, pdf, doc документы, для чего скорее всего будут использоватся сторонние библиотеки.

Comment: Это все вы будете генерировать на сервере иGWT этому не помешает. Вдумайтесь: GWT позволяет вам писать клиентскую часть на Java, которая потом перегоняется в JavaScript со всеми вытекающими последствиями.

Comment: Нет, вы не понимаете. На сервере всё будет как обычно. Так что на сервере вы можете работать с любыми современными базами, генерировать всё что угодно (для разных форматов для Java имеется множество библиотек). Платформа не имеет значения: на клиенте работает JavaScript, и работает он везде. На сервере работает обычная Java, которая работает более менее где угодно. <br/>
В таком случае оффлайн-версия не сможет ничего такого делать.. но ведь она и в обычном варианте не может работать, ведь веб-сервис будет недоступен.

Comment: С онлайн версией все понятно, серверную часть пишем как хотим и на чем хотим. А оффлайн версия должна работать автономно т.е. функии сервера должен будет выполнять сам клиент. Получается, если Java сервер генерировал документ с использованием сторонней библиотеки и производил вычисления с использованием нашей библиотеки.   
Вопрос, можно ли будет перенести функции сервера на клиента, чтобы эти же библиотеки находились у клиента и он мог их использовать?  
Наверное это возможно только, если эти библиотеки тоже написаны на JavaScript.

Comment: Ну да.. и маловероятно, что вы сможете из JavaScript сгенерировать и отобразить PDF.. а раз так, то оффлайн-функционал будет урезан

Answer (score 3):

По пункту 1. Включите сниффер на своём компьютере (Wireshark?), я думаю, вы будете отлично видеть содержание передач. Или вы его по https передаёте? REST - это же не способ шифрования, вроде... Или я ошибаюсь?

По пункту 3. Если используете AWT, то могут различаться. Если Swing - должны выглядеть одинаково. Имеет смысл скриншоты приложить.

По пункту 4. Если вас это беспокоит, может (если пока стадия разработки) лучше без апплета обойтись? Какой функционал вы в него закладываете, который нельзя было бы средствами самого браузера (javascript в первую очередь) реализовать?

Comment: <blockquote>Или вы его по https передаёте? REST это же не способ шифрования, вроде...</blockquote>  
<a href="http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/intro-ws_ru.html">тут<a> прочитал, что у SOAP спектр операций шире, чем у REST, особенно в области безопасности  
  
Используем Swing, но почему-то netbeans в класс панели прописал подключение AWT библиотек  
   import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

Comment: Это потому, что Swing надстроен над AWT. Так что нет ничего страшного в том, чтобы использовать некоторые готовые классы.

Comment: <blockquote>Какой функционал вы в него закладываете, который нельзя было бы средствами самого браузера (javascript в первую очередь) реализовать?</blockquote>
Действительно, javascript было бы неплохо использовать. Пользовательский интерфейс довольно сложный, много форм, много элементов, много динамики.  
Java привлекает удобностью разработки на netbeans, GUI, клиента веб-службы (как и самого сервера), хорошим ООП (не знаю как на javascript). Не знаю просто, как все это делается на javascript?  
Может ли javascript подключать Java библиотеки?

Comment: Вам следует посмотреть в сторону GWT. Это как раз то, что вы хотите.

Comment: <blockquote>Вам следует посмотреть в сторону GWT. Это как раз то, что вы хотите.</blockquote>  
Использование GWT разве снимает вопрос с iOS?

Comment: Да. Ведь GWT транслируется в JavaScript.

Comment: Хм. Честно говоря по Вашим вопросам мне кажется, что Вам имело бы смысл нанять на несколько дней консультанта нормального (на веблансе или ещё где спросить), чтобы вник в суть вашей затеи и помог Вам определиться с технологиями. По-видимому Вы не очень хорошо в этой области разбираетесь (это не укор, не подумайте) - поэтому чтобы избежать плохих технологических решений из-за которых Вы потом можете потерять кучу времени и денег - лучше заранее озаботиться конкретными советами какого-нибудь гуру. К сожалению форумы в этом мало помогут (т.к. надо чтоб человек именно вник).

Comment: Т.е. пишем Java приложение на GWT, транслируем в JavaScript и развертываем на сервере, а оффлайн версия это просмотр локальной копии данной страницы?   
Интересует вопрос закрытости некоторой части кода, ведь локальная версия будет целиком лежать у клиента?  
<b>UPD</b>  
<a href="http://hashcode.ru/users/3152/rodiongork">@RodionGork</a>, к сожалению ни одного такого гуру в городе я не знаю, у нас это плохо развито еще, раньше писали только настольные приложения.

Comment: Да. Но обфусцированный код будет выглядеть довольно жутко. Попробуйте, например, почитать исходники gmail..